# Camera ip with Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ip, camera

I'm new to this. I would like to know if it's possible to view an IP camera on Ubuntu server as if it were a Network Video Recorder (NVR), just for viewing. I want it to be visible on the same device through HDMI, resembling an NVR where cameras are displayed upon startup.
more than anything in Ubuntu server why I don't have many resources

Comment: Ubuntu server normally do not have any GUI. They are command line only. That means they can't show any pictures or video.